# Web site email address standard options/techniques

Tags: email, html-email

I'm designing a website, I want to display and email address on the website. Now on many websites, you can click on the email address and either outlook, gmail or whatever client will popup with the email address pre-inserted into that mail client. Other pages let you type your email content inside the web page and send the email to the email address on the website via some mail server. I know you can use Swift mailer with php for that...

Now what are some standard practices? Also, is it possible to detect whether a user is signed in into gmail (for example) and subsequently opening the web site email address inside a new mail as a recipient for him/her?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do either one.  The former situation you described is probably the easiest.  You can make links `<a href="mailto:your@email.com">E-mail us!</a>` which will open the user's default e-mail client; or you can create a form and use, in your case, PHP to send the mail.

Comment: awesome stuff, thank you...exactly what I was looking for. I know there had to be some easy method...I'm building my first info page, so I don't know

Answer (score 1):

1) `mailto:email@addy.here` is the native HTML technique which requires a client side mail client just like you've mentioned.

2) Other technique which uses `<form>` tags and sends e-mail server side is an alternative way but you need to take care of more cases in this scenerio.

a) You need to be careful about the security of your web page/server. There are many hack techniques which allows hackers to spam over your web site.

b) Don't forget about the limits of your hosting. There might be a per day e-mail limit which may cause you troubles.

So, choose the method depending on your site's needs and traffic.

Comment: thank you. Regarding the security, how to you secure your email address with the client side html request mailto:email@gmail.com ?

Comment: Security is mainly the server-side problem. For client-side usage, only problem i see is the e-mail sniffer bots which may cause huge spams. My advice is to use JavaScript to create content on click event dynamically. So, e-mail snifferbots would be fooled.

Comment: so it would be something like: $('a').click(function() {
$('a').attr("href", "mailto:email@gmail.com")}); ?

Comment: try not to write e-mail address in one piece. check the link i've just sent.

Comment: your code seems to be ok but you are using jquery so it will be a little bit different in your case. there are hundereds of examples on the web of course. just search the subject a little.

Comment: thank again...one more question, I read the link you gave me, where exactly do you enter your email address in the "advanced encoding"?

Comment: it's in the unescape() function but in encrypted form. to achieve that, you need to convert your e-mail to uri encoded form. the form at the link i've given before does that for you. if you want to code a similar function, here is the required character code list -> http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php